# How to see/get all wall posts of a specific Public Figure

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the posts of a specific public person.

I noticed that it is possible to do get the posts of a specific page through the FB API through the Graph Developer page i.e:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=EuropeanCommission%2Fposts&version=v2.5
```

Those are the posts for the European Commission.

How do I do something similar for a specific person i.e: https://www.facebook.com/zuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get the posts of a user profile by authorizing that specific user with the `user_posts` permission. Just because some posts are public does not mean you can get them with the API, the user has to authorize it specifically. I assume it´s because the user should always know what an App may do with his posts, if you could just grab public posts of any user, the user would never know.

It´s different for Pages, because they are public by definition - unless they are restricted by age or location, of course.